# Targeting a single <li> within <ul>

Tags: jquery

Quick question, I have an unordered list of "products" and I want the description to appear on a hover.  This works fine, except the animation is applied to every single product at once. How do I target just the list item I'm hovering on without giving a unique ID to every single li?  I'm sure the answer uses "this" but I haven't figured out how to do it successfully.

Products:

```
<ul id='products'>  
   <li>
     <div class='productDesc'>
        <img src = 'images/myImage1' />
        <p>
           Description 1...
        </p>
     </div>
   </li>

   <li>
     <div class='productDesc'>
        <img src = 'images/myImage2' />
        <p>
           Description 2...
        </p>
     </div>
   </li>

</ul>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#products li').hover(function(){
        $(".productDesc").fadeIn("slow");
    }, function(){
        $(".productDesc").fadeOut("slow");
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
 .productDesc{ display:none; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `$(this)` to get a reference to the hovered list item along with **[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** to get the child `.productDesc` inside that hovered list item:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#products li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".productDesc").fadeIn("slow");
    }, function(){
        $(this).find(".productDesc").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dky8r/)**

You can also shorten your code using **[.fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)** to toggle between `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#products li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".productDesc").fadeToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dky8r/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for the useful tips. I never knew about fadetoggle.  My problem when using "this" is that I didn't do a find of the productDesc class.  Good stuff!

Answer (score 2):

Use `this` (which will be the `li` you're hovering on), and find the `.productDesc` within that element.

```
$('#products li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".productDesc").fadeIn("slow");
}, function(){
        $(this).find(".productDesc").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#products li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(".productDesc", this).fadeToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/55TdY/)

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside the event handlers refers to the current target element, so you can find the `productDesc` element within the current `li` using

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#products li').hover(function () {
        $(this).find(".productDesc").fadeIn("slow");
    }, function () {
        $(this).find(".productDesc").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```