# Targeting a single <li> in dynamically loaded <ul>

Tags: jquery

This is a part B to a previous question:
[Targeting a single <li> within <ul>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666682/targeting-a-single-li-within-ul)

In the previous question I was displaying a product description by targeting a single `<li>` within an unordered list. That worked very well when the `<ul>` was hardcoded in my html. However, now I'm dynamically loading in the `<ul>` based on the navigation element that the user clicks on (shows all of the products under that category).  When I'm dynamically loading in the `<ul>` I can't seem to target the individual list items anymore.

**js:**

```
$('#products ul li img').hover(function(){
   $(this).find(".productDesc").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

If I take out the "ul li img", all of the products will show their descriptions simultaneously, but when I try to target an individual element, then no descriptions will appear at all.  Any ideas how to fix this?
(also tried `'#products ul'`, `'#products li'`, `'#products li img'`, `'#products ul li'`, and just about every permutation)

**html** (one of the `<ul>`'s will be loaded into a div called "products"):

```
<div id='products'> <!-- ul is loaded here --> </div>

<ul id='category1'> 
  <li>
    <img src='images/products/product1.jpg' />
    <div class='productDesc'>
       <p>description here</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <img src='images/products/product2.jpg' />
    <div class='productDesc'>
       <p>description here</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id='category2'> 
  <li>
    <img src='images/products/product3.jpg' />
    <div class='productDesc'>
       <p>description here</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <img src='images/products/product4.jpg' />
    <div class='productDesc'>
       <p>description here</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

etc...

****update****

The problem seems to lie in "this".  "this" refers to the list item that's being hovered on when the `<ul>` is hardcoded, but doesn't seem to refer to anything once it's loaded in dynamically. How can I get "this" to refer to the proper element?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** instead of `.find()` here since `.productDesc` is the next immediate sibling of your image:

```
$('#products ul li img').hover(function(){
    $(this).next().fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: I like the theory but it didn't fix the problem. hmmm

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation for this as it is created dynamically. Then you have to target its parent first, then only you can use the `.find()` method

```
$(document).on("hover","#products ul li img",function(){
  $(this).parent().find(".productDesc").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: The above code caused other issues, the ul's wouldn't load. So I think "this" seems to be the problem. If I write the following: `$('#products').hover(function(){ console.log(this);}`, the whole ul is being returned to the console. If I try to specify `$('#products ul')` then nothing is being returned to the console.  How should I target the "ul li img"?